Well-posedness of $\partial_t^3 u = \Delta u$
I am interested in the well-posedness of the following PDE:
$$\partial_t^3 u = \Delta u.$$
It resembles both the heat equation and the wave equation, but with a third-order time derivative.
Although this equation might seem unusual and lacks an obvious physical interpretation, I believe it is still worth studying. The simplicity of its form suggests that there may be techniques available for its analysis. Exploring such techniques could broaden our understanding and offer new insights.
Could anyone provide insights or references on how to approach the well-posedness of this PDE? Any suggestions on techniques or methods that could be applied here would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Try separation of variables.

You have an equation you’re interested in, but well-posedness refers to a problem statement. Are you thinking of an initial value problem or a problem with boundaries, or … ?

If $u=u(\mathbf x,t)$, taking the Fourier Transform wrt $\mathbf x$ the PDE converts to
$$\hat u_{ttt}=-|\mathbf k|^2\hat u$$
Assuming a solution of the form $\hat u\sim e^{rt}$, we obtain the following relation for $r$
$$r^3=-|\mathbf k|^2\implies r=e^{i(2n+1)\frac{\pi}{3}}|\mathbf k|^{\frac{2}{3}},\enspace n\in\mathbf Z$$
Choosing for instance $n=-1,0,1$ their corresponding $r$ are, respectively,
$$
\left\{\begin{aligned}
&r_1=e^{-i\frac{\pi}{3}}=\dfrac{1}{2}-i\dfrac{\sqrt 3}{2}\\
&r_2=e^{i\frac{\pi}{3}}=\dfrac{1}{2}+i\dfrac{\sqrt 3}{2}\\
&r_3=e^{i\pi}=-1
\end{aligned}\right.
$$
It follows that the general solution for the FT of $u$ is
$$\hat u=C_1(\mathbf k)\,e^{-|\mathbf k|^{\frac{2}{3}}t}+e^{\frac{1}{2}|\mathbf k|^{\frac{2}{3}}t}\left[C_2(\mathbf k)\,\sin\left(\frac{\sqrt 3}{2}|\mathbf k|^{\frac{2}{3}}t\right)+C_3(\mathbf k)\,\cos\left(\frac{\sqrt 3}{2}|\mathbf k|^{\frac{2}{3}}t\right)\right]$$
If we apply the corresponding boundary conditions we may be able to find these constants making it possible to compute the inverse. The final solution is then
$$u(\mathbf x,t)=\int_{\mathbf R^3}\hat u(\mathbf k,t)e^{i\mathbf k\cdot \mathbf x}\,\mathrm d^3\mathbf k$$

If you were to apply separation of variables you'd end up with results similar to heat equation's:
Say in cartesian coordinates, with $u=X(x)Y(y)Z(z)T(t)$ we'd have
$$\dfrac{\dddot T}{T}=\dfrac{X''}{X}+\dfrac{Y''}{Y}+\dfrac{Z''}{Z}$$
And so it'd reduce to $4$ Sturm-Liouville (if BCs are adequate) problems:
$$
\left\{\begin{aligned}
&\dddot T=(\lambda_x+\lambda_y+\lambda_z)T\\
&X''=\lambda_x X\\
&Y''=\lambda_y Y\\
&Z''=\lambda_z Z
\end{aligned}\right.
$$
Likewise, in cylindrical coordinates we'd get the following system
$$
\left\{\begin{aligned}
&\dddot T=\lambda_tT\\
&\rho^2R''+\rho R'+[(\lambda_z-\lambda_t)\rho^2-\lambda_\rho]R=0\\
&\Phi''=\lambda_\varphi \Phi\\
&Z''=\lambda_z Z
\end{aligned}\right.
$$
As for spherical coordinates, this other one:
$$
\left\{\begin{aligned}
&\dddot T=\lambda_tT\\
&r^2R''+2rR'-(\lambda_tr^2+\lambda_r)R=0\\
&\Phi''=\lambda_\varphi \Phi\\
&\dfrac{1}{\sin\theta}(\sin\theta\, \Theta')'+\left(\lambda_r+\dfrac{\lambda_\varphi}{\sin^2\theta}\right)\Theta=0
\end{aligned}\right.
$$
wherein the last ODE you can change coordinates like $\gamma=\cos\theta$ and obtain Legendre's equation if $\lambda_\varphi=0$ or the associated one otherwise.
